# How can I get actual text from an element that returns u'' when using element.text?

Tags: python, selenium

Here's the html of the element:

`<input type="text" class="GCPIA-YCORB GCPIA-YCHRB">`

Whenever I try to get the text from the element using element.text, it just returns u'' even though the element has text. Is there another method I can use to get the actual text from the element?

Comment: What about using `element.get_attribute('value')` ([docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute))?

Comment: Tried getting attribute of "value"?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've tried that method and it also returns u''.

Answer (score 1):

```
element.text
```

will return the `innerHtml` of the input element you are trying to fetch.  Since the input element is not a block level element, rather, it uses the `value` attribute to store it's content, then use exactly what alecxe had stated.

```
the_text = element.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: That also returns u''.